Understanding たらね in そりゃあそんな夜遅くに女の子が一人でシミュレーションゴルフに来てたらね
As a context, he once saw her playing golf simulation at night before:

I am not quite sure about たらね in his response:

そりゃああんな夜遅くに女の子が一人でシミュレーションゴルフに来てたらね

I think he said "if/when a women comes to play a golf at late night alone..." I am uncertain whether this たら is understood as "if" or "when." It depends on what he left out after たら. I think he was trying to add more details to his previous response:

そりゃああんな夜遅くに女の子が一人でシミュレーションゴルフに来てたら（藤波さんがそんなにゴルフ好きなのかは気になった）ね

Another possibility is that he is responding to her question そこですか:

そりゃあそんな夜遅くに女の子が一人でシミュレーションゴルフに来てたら（ちょっと気になるよ）ね

Which one is correct?

That たら-clause serves as the explanation for the previous conversation as a whole. But note that he is trying to generalize the situation to justify his doubts. You can translate this using "I" as the subject, but it's also fine to use "someone" in the translation, like this:

Well, if someone sees a girl coming to play simulation golf alone at such a late hour... (it's natural if they wonder if she loves golf so much)

